# Bluetooth reconnects to same device after navigation

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've the following situation using bluetooth:

There several bluetooth devices which we can connect to.

First time we load the fragment in which we control the device connection any attempt of connection is done to the indicated bluetooth device.

But if we navigateup from the fragment with findNaController().navigateUp() then the following error (among others, which I've managed to bypass by several hacks, happen), happens once the fragment is loaded again (despite being in theory completely created as if it were the first time, as in debug mode I've checked that goes through onCreateView method again).

No matter what bluetooth device we order it to connect to, despite having checked that the data that it's told to use to connect to the bluetooth device is the one it should be for that bluetooth device, it always connects to the last bluetooth device which was connected before the up navigation.

What could be causing this faulty behavior?

PD: I've only checked this to happen in device with API 23, not sure about others.